# ¿Como puedo crear un conteo?

Tags: php

como puedo crear un conteo regresivo que sea por días, horas, minutos y segundos, este conteo no hará que ejecute alguna función ni nada solo que cuando llegue a 0

00
DAYS
00
HOURS
00
MINUTES
00
SECONDS

Este se quede ahi hasta que le vuelva a colocar otro conteo regresivo.

Edit.

encontré esto

```
$rem = strtotime('2022-09-15 22:00:00') - time();
$day = floor($rem / 86400);
$hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
$min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
$sec = ($rem % 60);
```

Pero ¿como hago para que la cuenta regresiva sea dinámico? y no tener que estar recargando la pagina para ver cuanto queda.

Comment: Para mostrar cuánto falta para año nuevo: `echo (new DateTime('2023-01-01T00:00:00'))->diff( new DateTime('now') )->format('%a Dias %H Hrs %I Mins %S Segs');`.

Comment: php se ejecuta del lado del servidor, vos queres algo en js para que vaya modificando la cuenta ;)